# How to resample a raster with gdalogr:warpreproject or gdalogr:translate with non-default method

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, qgis-processing, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I would like to resample a raster to multiple rasters of a certain amount of pixels in width and height based on a bilinear resampling method.

However, I am not sure if the available syntax allows to do this from the QGIS Python console.

This works fine:

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:translate',{"INPUT":rlayer, "OUTSIZE":j, "OUTSIZE_PERC":False, "EXPAND":0, "PROJWIN":"%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), "OUTPUT":resampled})
```

For the snipped above the default resample method (nearest neighbor) is used. According to the  [gdal manual](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html), the method can be changed with the *-r* flag, but from [processing.alghelp("gdalogr:translate")](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/translate.html), this option seems to be unavailable.

Therefore, I thought of using [gdalogr:warpreproject](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_projections/warpreproject.html) instead, where the resampling method can be defined. However, now I cannot define the amount of pixels in width and height as indicated in the [gdal manual](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html), because the *TS* flag is not available according to [processing.alghelp("gdalogr:warpreproject")](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_projections/warpreproject.html).

Optimal would be something like:

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:warpreproject',{"INPUT":rlayer, "METHOD":1, "RAST_EXT":"%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),"TS":"%i,%i" % (j, j), "OUTPUT":resampled})
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried inserting those flags in the `extra` parameter of those algorithms?

Comment: Rather than use the processing.runalg function, you could import gdal and then call gdal.Translate() directly, which will give you all of its functionality.

Comment: Both sound like valid solutions, but I struggle finding syntax examples for defining the `extra` parameter and `gdal.Translate()` parameters in PyQGIS. Could you provide a short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct syntax for defining the `extra` parameter when using `gdal` methods in QGIS processing scripts:

```
"EXTRA": "-r {bilinear}"
```

The problem above is therefore solved with:

`processing.runalg('gdalogr:translate',{"INPUT":rlayer, "OUTSIZE":j, "OUTSIZE_PERC":False, "EXPAND":0, "EXTRA": "-r {bilinear}","PROJWIN":"%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), "OUTPUT":resampled})`

I assume further `extra` parameters from the [gdal manual](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) can similarly be set.